# what is mean by $indexes in installschema?? what it do?

Tags: magento2, database, index, install-script, mysql-indexes

as i was creating new module in magento2 which has table so when i was going through existing modules i found this function

```
$indexes= array();
```

we are just  creating array ok fine.

but if you go further you find this function

```
foreach($indexes AS $index)
            {
                $table->addIndex(
                $installer->getIdxName($tableName,array($index)),
                array($index)
                );
            }
```

i did not get what exactly going through and why we are using this $indexes array.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not totally sure what you're asking exactly.

Basically the array you're describing is an array of database indexes.

In your case, it's empty but it usually contains a list of table columns that will be used for database index.

Here's a very simple example for the `cms_block_store` table:

```
->addIndex(
        $installer->getIdxName('cms_block_store', ['store_id']),
        ['store_id']
    )
```

The first parameter generates an unique index name:

```
$installer->getIdxName('cms_block_store', ['store_id'])
```

The second parameter is an array of columns that will be used for the index.

```
['store_id']
```

There can also be a third parameter for option such as the index type:

```
['type' => AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT]
```

The details of the `addIndex` method can be found under `Magento/Framework/DB/Ddl/Table.php`